# AWS S3 using Ceph how to provide a url for an object

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ceph, cephfs

I'm starting to work with `AWS SDK S3` with `Ceph` storage platform,
and my server needs to provide a URL to some large objects without getting the objects themselves, but only a URL to access the object.

Is there a way to do so with`Ceph`?

With `AWS S3` I just used the [S3RequestPresigner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/classes/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.s3requestpresigner-1.html) but it does not seems to work with
`Ceph`